# What is the identification procedure that registers a mobile device on a subscriber account and installs purchased content?

Tags: security, mobile, copy-protection

We know there are several moving parts to a system like the apple store or google play. At the very least;

- The device has a unique hardware id or sim card
- The user has a login/pass
- The "store" site has some crypto

In what order and format (cypher/plaintext) is this data exchanged between the device and store software before content is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very general question, and the answer will differ depending on the application interface you're using.

Generally:

- Content is encrypted. You need a "key" to unlock it.
- The "key" is attained by synchronizing the local profile with a master server.
- Typical authentication methods are used to login to the master server.
- All communication to the master server is typically over SSL/encrypted channels.
- Your profile on the master server will contain all the purchases you have performed, and this is used to generate keys to unlock encrypted content.
- Keys can be revoked by the master server if necessary.

Its also likely that *all* content, including free content, is encrypted, and requires a key from the master server to *unlock* and use/execute. This is all pretty standard authentication/DRM type mechanics.

Comment: Is the device id in this local profile?

Comment: Would depend on whether you're intending on limiting your installs to a number of devices or not. EG: Steam appears to have a separate list of "authorized computers" which you can download content on, I don't know if actual installs per machine are tracked (possibly for stats, unlikely for DRM)

Comment: Thamks for the comments. I will be awarding ypu this bounty. Would you mind if I PM/email you with any questions that arise in development that I cannot solve myself?